# How do I get create extra large Buttons in react-bootstrap not just `size="lg"`

Tags: reactjs, button, size, react-bootstrap

I look at the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/) and can only see the `size="lg"` as larges but I would like bigger like this image show:

Image:

[image]

And what I have now is this using: `size="lg"`

[image]

Can I do this bigger style with react-bootstrap maybe using css? I could not finds details when searching around also I'm a bit new to this. Also the text input and button as well should be cool if they where bigger.

Oh yes here is my React Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Navbar, Nav, Form, FormControl, Button, NavDropdown, NavItem, Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem';
import logo1 from '../../assets/The first 100 weeks in pictures and more7.png';

class NavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { showMenu: false };
        this.handleMenuClick = this.handleMenuClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleMenuClick() {
        const { showMenu } = this.state;
        this.setState({ showMenu: !showMenu });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top">
                    <Container fluid>
                        <Col md="auto">
                            <Navbar.Brand href="#home" className="img-container">
                                <img alt="" src={logo1} />
                            </Navbar.Brand>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="auto">
                            <Nav.Item>
                                <Form inline>
                                    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Title, event, date" className="mr-sm-2" size="lg" />
                                    <Button variant="outline-info" size="lg">
                                        Search
                                    </Button>
                                </Form>
                            </Nav.Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="auto">
                            <Button variant="primary" size="lg">
                                Articles
                            </Button>{' '}
                            <Button variant="primary" size="lg">
                                Timeline
                            </Button>{' '}
                            <Button variant="primary" size="lg">
                                About
                            </Button>{' '}
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="auto">
                            <Nav.Item>
                                <NavDropdown title="Events" id="basic-nav-dropdown" className="justify-content-left">
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Divider />
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                                </NavDropdown>
                            </Nav.Item>{' '}
                        </Col>
                    </Container>
                </Navbar>
            </>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { articles: state.rootReducer.remoteArticles };
};

const Aaa = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(NavBar);
export default Aaa;
```

Comment: Both answer explain it so I accept the first! Thanks I learn so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the docs for custom sizes: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/theming/#custom-styles-variants

```
<style type="text/css">
  {`
    .btn-flat {
      background-color: purple;
      color: white;
    }

    .btn-huge {
      padding: 5rem 10rem;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .btn-small {
      padding: 0.2rem 0.2rem;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  `}
</style>

<Button variant="flat" size="huge">
  Hello World
</Button>
<Button variant="flat" size="small">
  Hello World
</Button>
```

[image: Edit young-field-ppqu5]

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do this via CSS. Create your own custom size by defining a css class matching the component as outlined here:

see https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/theming/

In your example I would create a separate file such as ./styles/styles.css which you import into your app or component's js file (usually the former so you can use it everywhere in your application). It's a better practice to break it out like this rather then to define it inline as they're showing in the example so that you can reuse it. In there you can define any styles that you want such as to solve your problem:

```
.btn-xxl {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

then import the file into your app or component's js file..

```
import './styles/styles.css'
```

then use your new tag in your JSX..

```
<Button variant="primary" size="xxl">
  Articles
</Button>{' '}
```

That way you can use the xxl size elsewhere in your application as well and if you ever want to change it you have only to do so back in your styles.css file. If you start creating a lot of css like this you break styles.css out into separate files which styles.css imports.